# Solving a separable differential equation: What's wrong with my calculation?

Tags: calculus, integration

Solve the following separable differential equation:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(-4)\cdot e^y \cdot cos(4x)$$

My answer (which is incorrect but I don't know why):
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(-4)\cdot e^y \cdot cos(4x)$$

$$= dy = (-4)\cdot e^y \cdot cos(4x)dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{-4e^y}dy=cos(4x)dx$$
$$= \int\frac{1}{-4e^y}dy=\int cos(4x)dx$$
$$= 4e^{-y}=\frac{1}{4}sin(4x)+c$$
$$= e^{-y}=\frac{1}{16}sin(4x)+c$$
$$= ln(e^{-y})=ln(\frac{1}{16}sin(4x)+c)$$
$$= y=-ln(\frac{1}{16}sin(4x)+c)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fifth line of working you should have $\frac{1}{4}e^{-y}$. Otherwise I see no issues.